# Get access to a user controls custom properties in a master page from a content page

Tags: asp.net

I have a master page with a user control added. The user control has properties, price and exchange rate.

I can get the control from a normal page by using master.findcontrol but it sees it as just a normal user control, so i cant get access to the controls properties, price or exchange rates.

Is there a way to solve this?

Thanks to all who view

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the control to your custom control in order to access the properties of your custom control,

```
var control = (YourCustomControl)Master.FindControl("YourCustomControl");
```

I guess you have not exposed any properties for your custom control, Try the following,

```
public partial class YourControl: System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
  public string textboxtext{
  get { return tb_Textbox.Text ;} 
  set { tb_Texbox.Text = value; }
  }
}
```

Once you create properties for all the customizable properties for your custom control, you then can access or modify them.

Comment: @WesleySkeen Are you not accessing your control properties using control.PropertyToAccess ? Can you please explain a bit of what are you trying to do? BTW Did you correctly expose the properties you want in your control to be modified as Public Properties in your controls code behind?

Comment: I am referencing it like                                     UserControl Cart1 = (UserControl)Master.FindControl("Cart1")           Cart1 is on the master page and all the user controls properties are set to public

Comment: Not all properties internal to your UserControl can be modified externally, Have you tried creating your own properties in code behind of your UserControl.ascx ? as shown above

Answer (score 0):

Why not expose your custom control as a property of the masterpage.  Then you can reference it like:

```
Master.YourCustomControl.YourCustomProperty
```

Comment: How do you expose the custom control?

Comment: Here is a description how to do this:  http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/013107-1.aspx